# map like MapTypeId.TERRAIN with dark water

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

Hello
I can darken the water at the same time changing to a styled map so other values get reset. What I want is a map with green landscape like MapTypeId.TERRAIN has and darker water. I could manage make the water darker and now also want green landscape same way MapTypeId.TERRAIN has. Can you recommend a way? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, the [Google Styled Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps) cannot be applied to map types other than the default `ROADMAP` type. This was confirmed by a Google Employee on the mailing list on May 31st 2010:

- [Google Maps API v3 Re: Using Styled Maps with TERRAIN map type?](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-js-api-v3@googlegroups.com/msg03870.html)

However, if you simply want a greener terrain with dark water, you can still style the default `ROADMAP` to look something like this:

[image: aGoogle Maps Dark Water Style Demo]

Example source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Dark Water Style Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     var darkStyle = [
       {
         featureType: "landscape",
         elementType: "all",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "on" },
           { hue: "#1aff00" },
           { lightness: -17 }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "water",
         elementType: "all",
         stylers: [
           { hue: "#1900ff" },
           { invert_lightness: true },
           { lightness: -56 },
           { saturation: 31 },
           { visibility: "simplified" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "administrative",
         elementType: "all",
         stylers: [
           { gamma: 0.82 },
           { visibility: "on" },
           { lightness: -18 },
           { hue: "#00ff4d" },
           { saturation: 27 }
         ]
       }
     ];

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
         mapTypeIds: [
          'darkwater', 
          google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
          google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
         ]
       },
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0),
       zoom: 1,
       mapTypeId: 'darkwater'
     });

     map.mapTypes.set(
       'darkwater', new google.maps.StyledMapType(darkStyle, { 
         name: 'Dark' 
       })
     );
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can style your map visually with this map:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Comment: Consider expanding your answer with some excerpt from the referenced page. See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for details why bare links are not considered good answers.